# Multiple Class / ID and Class Selectors with : active state in IE and Opera

Tags: html, css, browser

i designed a button in CSS3 with multiple class selectors. I would like to add a active function when someone press the button but this does not work in all IE and the Opera Browser.

CSS

```
    .large.button:active {

         padding: 13px 18px 14px 18px;

    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="large rounded dark outline">

         <div class="large rounded green button"><span>Button</span></div>

    </div>
```

Can someone please tell me why this does not work in IE and Opera? it works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can we see your HTML?  Perhaps create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Hi, i have add the HTML :)

Comment: `:active` is for links (`<a>`).

Comment: @Vucko - Why does it work in the other browsers then? And is there a solution for divs? Thanks!

Comment: So is there no solution with divs?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the text inside the `<span>` is not activating the `:active` psudo class on your div.  If you put the `class:"large button"` on the span it should work.

Here is a JSFiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5NJCA/5/

Comment: And what is intended? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! But this still does not help becouse i don`t know what you mean ;)

Comment: So is there no solution with divs?

Comment: I have edited my answer because the previous information was incorrect.  There is now a jsfiddle with an example of the cause of the problem.  I hope this helps.